# how to find length of float number in C WITHOUT using strings...?

Tags: c

for example length of 1.54 is 4 including the decimal point. i need a C code for finding the length in the same way but without strings and also snprintf

Comment: Did you tried anything related to this requirement?

Comment: +1 @Chandru and also... why do you need to do that without using strings?

Comment: The length of a floating point value is whatever precision you specify. You won't get a number like "1.54" unless you ask for two decimal places.

Comment: Pretty easy. Just multiply it up at 10 untill the number is a full int with not decimal point (check that by '(int)num == num') and then divide it by 10 and every division add 1 to length variable (that was initialized to zero first) untill the number is zero. Both while loops

Answer (score 3):

Calculating the length of a floating-point number decimal representation doesn't make much sense, as its underlying representation is binary. For example 0.1 in decimal form yields an infinite  number of digits in binary.

C has no intrinsic decimal type, so you will have to represent your number with some ad-hoc type, and shave off insignificant digits on the right. C-strings are not the worse choice for that.

Answer (score 0):

The length is set by you at the moment you print it.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
  float x = 0.2;
  double y = 0.2;

  int size_x = sizeof(float);
  int size_y = sizeof(double);

  printf("Variable x has a size of %i. But i can print if as different lengths: %f, %3.2f, %g, %e\n", size_x, x, x, x, x);
  printf("Variable y has a size of %i. But i can print if as different lengths: %lf, %3.2lf, %lg, %le\n", size_y, y, y, y, y);

  return 0;
}
```